# Adding input capabilities to HTML select option dropdown

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, html-input

Right now the search_type which JS uses later is always "people" as can be seen in the hidden input field.

How can I make it so that the selected option's value is the value tied to the name "search_type"?

```
<input type="hidden" name="search_type" value="people"> <!-- This obviously needs to change-->
<div class="medium-4 columns">
   <select>
      <option value="default">All Categories</option>
      <option value="people">People</option>
      <option value="items">Items</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the name of all the options' names to search_type but this did not work. I have also tried other things, but can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the Javascript line that calls it:

```
search_type: $('input[name="search_type"]').val(),
```

Note: I am working in Zurb Foundation

Comment: Could you just use the `name=search_type` property on your `select` tag?

Comment: Nope, then the JS can't find it. I think this may be because it is no longer in an input field.

Comment: I am going to do what you said and change the javascript to look for selects and see if that solves it.

Comment: That worked and I feel dumb, Thanks WookieCoder

Comment: No worries, that's why we're here. I'll make it an answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, there is no need to add another input field when you already have a perfectly usable one! change your code so that the `<select>` includes the name attribute, like so, and get rid of the hidden input:

```
<div class="medium-4 columns">
   <select name="search_type">
      <option value="default">All Categories</option>
      <option value="people">People</option>
      <option value="items">Items</option>
   </select>
</div>
```